# how to assign comma separated string of length of 50k to any variable in strored procedure?

Tags: t-sql

I wanted to convert comma separated values into rows in my stored procedure so for the string having length 50k?

I am passing this comma separated string to procedure from c# application

```
create procedure sp_1
(
    @Arraylist Nvarchar(max) 
)
as
begin 
Declare @areaIdarray_list nvarchar(max)
 Set @areaIdarray_list = @Arraylist

select rm.AreaId 
from table1 rm
where rm.AreaId in(
    select cast(value as int) 
    from dbo.fn_Split(@areaIdarray_list,',')
)
end
```

It's working also but only up to the length of an 8k string.
I want to do this for the string having the length of 50k.
i.e. `exec sp_1('1,2,3,..........')` and so on till 50k.

Comment: It's not the assignment to the variable - `nvarchar(max)` can hold up to 2GB of data - it must the the `fn_split` that takes in a `varchar(8000)`. Still, a table valued parameter is the better option.

Comment: Please could you add the code of your `Function`, then we might be able to guide you from there...

Answer (score 0):

> I am passing this comma separated string to procedure from c# application

Since you are not working with an ancient version of SQL Server (considering `nvarchar(max)` was added in 2008) the best way to do it is not to use comma delimited strings at all.
Instead, pass a table valued parameter from c# to the stored procedure.

Create a user defined table type:

```
create type dbo.ids as table
(
    id int not null primary key
)
```

Then all you need is in your procedure is this:

```
create procedure stpGetAreas
(
    @tvp dbo.ids readonly
)
as
select rm.AreaId 
from table1 rm
join @tvp tvp 
    on rm.AreaId = tvp.id
```

c# supports different ways of connecting to a database, but you didn't specify which one you are using and I can't show you how your c# code should look without knowing how are you connecting to the database.

Comment: Thanks Zohar Peled. i used the approch given by you and now it's working. thanks for the solution.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)